# Idempotency in Matrices and deducing Linear Map Compositions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, idempotents

[image]

Hello, could anyone help me out with these two questions.

With question d) I know that because D is an idempotent matrix, then In - D must also be idempotent through:

(In-D)(In-D) = In-2Dn+D = In - D

And also the relation between the linear maps:

S: Rn -> Rn has matrix D

S' : Rn -> Rn had matrix In - D

Then the dot product of S and S' is equal to the multiplication of D and In-D.

But that's as far as I can get with d)

And with e) the only thing I have proved so far is the E is idempotent due to when it's squared it returns E but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for d:** $S \circ S' = D \circ (I_n - D) = D \circ I_n - D \circ D$.

**Hint for e:** For every $n$, $T^{n} = T \circ T^{n-1}$. For example,
$$
T^3 = T \circ T^2 = T \circ T = T.
$$

Comment: Thanks. So does this mean I can deduce that T^9001 is the same as T as simplifying along the equation just results in giving T back, since idempotent? Also I understand what you are hinting for d) but I still unsure on what is actually means to find or deduce a linear map. Like what is the notation for this?

Comment: @Taylor Yes to your first question. To you're second question, $S \circ S' = 0$ is probably the answer they're looking for. "Deduce the linear map" as a phrase is unfortunately strangely phrased and too vague to interpret without context

Comment: So would it make sense of me to say this for deducing the linear map: for S o S' : Rn -> Rn, where (SoS')(D) := S(S'(D)) = the Zero vector.

Comment: @Taylor I don't understand why you have written $(S \circ S')(D)$. Is $D$ supposed to denote the matrix $D$ or a vector in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: The matrix D. Because at the end of the question it says based on its associated matrix and I thought that's what D was.

Comment: @Taylor But $S \circ S'$ is a map from $\Bbb R^n$, so any input to the map needs to be a vector. We would instead say that for any vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$, we have 
$$
(S \circ S')(x) = S(S'(x)) = \vec 0.
$$

Comment: Ah okay I understand. I'm just lost on what an associated matrix is. My university notes tell me frequently what associated matrices must satisfy but never actually state what an associated matrix is.

Comment: @Taylor For a linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, the "associated matrix" is the matrix $A$ for which $T(x) = Ax$. In (d), "based on its associated matrix" can be stated more clearly as "in terms of $D$".